# Can't get AngularJS and D3 to change header colour

Tags: typescript

I'm new to angular and d3 so apologies for the basic nature of the question.
The page displays ok but the h1 heading doesn't change colour. I'm using visual studio code.
Thanks.

app.component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js">

d3.select('h1').style('color', 'darkblue');

function myFunction() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('my-div');
    elem.style.color = 'blue';
}
</script>
</head>

<div id="my-div" style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

//d3.select('h1').style('color', 'darkblue');


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-d3-app';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<script>` is running before the rest of the html has loaded, so when `d3.select('h1').style('color', 'darkblue');` executes `<h1>` does not exist yet.

HTML is executed as it loads, from the top of the document down. So to get that to work you need to put the script after:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="my-div" style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
    d3.select('h1').style('color', 'darkblue');

    function myFunction() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('my-div');
        elem.style.color = 'blue';
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: A note, since you are using a data binding framework like angular, running script manipulating the DOM in the template is an anti-pattern. It would be much better to do this in the angular component, something like:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {

 d3.select('h1').style('color', 'darkblue');
}
```

Have a look for some guides like [here](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/integrating-d3js-with-angular-5-0-848ed45a8e19) and [here](https://medium.com/netscape/visualizing-data-with-angular-and-d3-209dde784aeb).

Comment: Here is a bin of it working: https://jsbin.com/fizeceq/edit?html,output

Comment: I cut and pasted your html code but it still doesn't work in visualStudioCode.

Comment: Originally I was trying to use the angular component. So what I have is shown below, but still doesn't work.

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-d3-app';
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    d3.select('h1').style('color', 'darkblue');
  }

}

Comment: Sounds like it could be an issue with your setup for how you are running it in VS Code. Try opening the html file straight in a browser to see it working, then working backwards from there to try find your issue.

Comment: Here is an angular bin of you code working with Angular: https://codesandbox.io/s/30zv345z7p
See src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Sean. I changed my app.module.ts to use double quotes and added public and void to ngAfterContentInit and it start working. I then undid changes to find out the problem and it continued to work! Complete mystery.

Comment: A pleasure, glad I could assist! Strange, it could be a build issue or browser caching issue maybe? Either way glad you got it working. If you are happy with this as the answer to your problem, could you mark it as solved for anyone else who comes by?